# Xamarin Android - app reinstalling fresh each time in debug mode

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.android

I've read through all previous answers on this.
This used to work and suddenly stopped.
Attached are all the screenshots for my config - it's driving me bonkers - any clues ?

Link to images as imgur is not currently working for some reason !
[Images of my setup in Visual Studio 15.9.11](https://postimg.cc/gallery/2xyltjc6g/)

Answer (score 1):

The issue has to do with Google Drive app data backup/automatic restore being enabled. Turning that off and using the configuration in the screenshots in the original question resolved the issue for us.